# While using Format function in SQL Server 2019 (v15.0) I get a CLR Error. How to solve it?

Tags: sql-server

We are using SQL Server 2019 (v15.0), and suddenly the same query containing the `Format` function that used to work earlier has started showing an error

> Failed to initialize the Common Language Runtime (CLR) v4.0.30319 with HRESULT 0x80131701. You may fix the problem and try again later

We have tried

- Using the .NET Framework repair tool
- Restating the SQL Server services
- Restarting the server

Comment: There is no SQL Server 19, what version are you really using? What is the output of `SELECT @@VERSION` when you execute it via SSMS? SQL Server 2019 is version 15 and the latest SQL Server 2022 is version 16.

Comment: my mistake, our server is sql server 2019 (15.0.2080.9)

Comment: Is it just FORMAT that gives this error or also things like TRY_PARSE, and Geography data types (I.e. other places that CLR is used)

Comment: @AaronBertrand - time to play my favorite game: "what's that knob for?". Are you saying that there is literally no use case for the FORMAT function? For me, I tend to use it in ad hoc queries to put commas in big numbers to get a sense of magnitude. Is it "terrible for performance"? Probably. Do I care that I had to wait an extra 500ms waiting for results to come back that will save me a couple of seconds counting digits? Unequivocally no.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - there's a difference between warning people and telling them not to use something full stop. Also, fwiw, not only do I know what point you were trying to make, I generally agree with it. It's the *how* that I disagree with. We choose how we want to inculcate those who might be new to the game; gently or "hold out your hand so I can hit it with a ruler". And, to paraphrase someone who I respect, I think you're well aware of the point I'm trying to make; it's up to you whether or not you agree with it.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - it's clear to me that this conversation won't be productive; I yield. Out.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I would venture to suggest that if this error is appearing then OP probably has other issues, so avoiding `FORMAT` is not much of a solution

Comment: Which version of .NET Framework are you using? Exact build number please. Have you tried the usual Windows repair `dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth`

Comment: Sounds like your .NET framework is broken. Did you change anything on the server? Or done some windows updates?